# SQL Server Timezone

Tags: sql-server, timezone

In SQL Server 2008 R2 if I do:

```
select SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
```

I get back GMT -6.

The TimeZone in Windows that SQL Server is running on is set GMT -7.

Any ideas why there is a difference? Is there somewhere in SQL Server I need to set the TimeZone?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/03/18/using-time-zone-data-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess this is due to Daylight Saving Time being active.  Your timezone is officially titled "GMT-7" meaning that normally (not in the Daylight Saving Time part of the year) your time is 7 hours earlier than GMT.  But during Daylight Saving Time, that time is adjusted (usually by an hour, but can differ by timezone).  So if you were currently in Daylight Saving Time, even though you are in the "GMT-7" timezone, your clock is currently only GMT-6 (6 hours earlier than GMT).  I suspect SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() is telling you your actual offset from GMT at the moment as opposed to your timezone's "normal" offset from GMT.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677334.aspx) says SQL Server uses the Windows settings:

> SQL Server 2012 obtains the date and time values by using the
>   GetSystemTimeAsFileTime() Windows API.

Perhaps you have to restart the SQL Server service after you change the time zone?